# Why isn't my variable expanded in this string?

Tags: php

```
$q = $_GET['q'];

// Load and parse the XML document 

$rss =  simplexml_load_file('http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?lang=en&q=$q&rpp=100&page=1');
```

This returns results containing `"$q"` instead of results containing the value of `$q`. Why won't it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your quotes to double quotes in the simplexml_load_file line

```
$q = $_GET['q'];

// Load and parse the XML document
$rss = simplexml_load_file("http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?lang=en&q=$q&rpp=100&page=1");
```

PHP will automatically resolve the variable **only** if the string is in double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [double quotes to have variables getting expanded](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing):

> **Variable parsing**
>
> When a string is specified in double quotes or with heredoc, variables are parsed within it.

So:

```
"http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?lang=en&q=$q&rpp=100&page=1"
```

But it would be even better if you use proper URL escaping with [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode):

```
'http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?lang=en&q='.urlencode($q).'&rpp=100&page=1'
```

You can also do that when declaring the `$q` variable and then use the double quoted string delcaration:

```
$q = urlencode($_GET['q']);
$rss = simplexml_load_file("http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?lang=en&q=$q&rpp=100&page=1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes.